# Fix Unicode Decode Error Without Specifying Encoding='UTF-8'

Tags: python-unicode

I am getting the following error:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 560: ordinal not in range(128)

I find this very weird given that my `.csv` file doesn't have special characters. Perhaps it has special characters that specify header rows and what not, idk.

But the main problem is that I don't actually have access to the source code that reads in the file, so I cannot simply add the keyword argument `encoding='UTF-8'`. I need to figure out which encoding is compatible with `codecs.ascii_decode(...)`. I DO have access to the `.csv` file that I'm trying to read, and I can adjust the encoding to that, but not the source file that reads it.

I have already tried exporting my `.csv` file into Western (ASCII) and Unicode (UTF-8) formats, but neither of those worked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "*my .csv file doesn't have special characters*" - are you sure? What does the file actually look like? The error says it detected byte 0xF4 in the file, and that byte is not valid in ASCII, and in UTF-8 it is only valid for Unicode characters in the range `U+10000 .. U+10FFFF`

Comment: Just regular alphanumeric characters. It's possible that the weird characters are part of the other components of the csv file.

Comment: But again, the main point is that I need to be able to figure out what the correct encoding is so as to not break codecs.ascii_decode(...).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Had nothing to do with unicode shenanigans, my script was writing a parquet file when my Cloud Formation Template was expecting a csv file. Thanks for the help.